# Dealing with nulls that result in duplicates in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am pretty new to using UNIONS in big query and am trying to fill some of the nulls with data from different fields

What have I tried:

The COALESCE function since it can be used used to select the first non-null value are replaced with the first non-null value and thought that would help handing the nulls in the dates.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as again this is something that I am new to and still learning.

This is my query for reference:

```
SELECT
  ClientID,
  Staff,
  AppointmentStatus AS `Appointment Status`,
  COALESCE(DateOfService, ApptDate) AS `Date of Service`,
  ApptDate AS `Appointment Date`
FROM (
  SELECT
    b.clientID AS ClientID,
    b.staff_name AS Staff,
    a.status_value AS AppointmentStatus,
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", b.date_of_service) AS DateOfService,
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", a.appointment_date) AS ApptDate
  FROM
    billing_table b
    LEFT JOIN appointment_table a ON b.clientID = a.clientID AND b.join_to_billing = a.join_to_billing 
  WHERE
    CAST(b.date_of_service AS DATE) BETWEEN '2022-11-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
    AND (
      a.status_value IS NOT NULL OR b.date_of_service IS NOT NULL OR a.appointment_date IS NOT NULL
    )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    a.clientID AS ClientID,
    a.staff_name AS Staff,
    a.status_value AS AppointmentStatus,
    NULL AS DateOfService,
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", a.appointment_date) AS ApptDate
  FROM
    appointment_table a
  WHERE
    CAST(a.appointment_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2022-11-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
    AND (
      a.status_value IS NOT NULL OR a.appointment_date IS NOT NULL
    )
) 
ORDER BY ClientID
```

**This is the current results: **

| ClientID | Staff | Status | DateOfSrv | ApptDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | NULL | 11/01/2022 |
| 2 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | 11/05/2022 | 11/05/2022 |
| 2 | DOE,JOHN | NULL | 11/05/2022 | NULL |
| 3 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | 11/10/2022 | NULL |
| 3 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | NULL | 11/10/2022 |

However,

**Desired Results: **

| ClientID | Staff | Status | DateOfSrv | ApptDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | 11/01/2022 | 11/01/2022 |
| 2 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | 11/05/2022 | 11/05/2022 |
| 3 | DOE,JOHN | Scheduled | 11/10/2022 | 11/10/2022 |

Answer (score 0):

Since your results are essentially where you need them to be and you just need to drop rows containing `NULL` fields, you can simply wrap your results once more to only return those rows:

```
SELECT
  b.ClientID,
  b.Staff,
  b.AppointmentStatus AS `Appointment Status`,
  b.dos AS `Date of Service`,
  b.ApptDate AS `Appointment Date`
FROM (
  SELECT
    ClientID,
    Staff,
    AppointmentStatus,
    COALESCE(DateOfService, ApptDate) AS `dos`,
    ApptDate
  FROM (
    SELECT
      b.clientID AS ClientID,
      b.staff_name AS Staff,
      a.status_value AS AppointmentStatus,
      FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", b.date_of_service) AS DateOfService,
      FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", a.appointment_date) AS ApptDate
    FROM
      billing_table b
      LEFT JOIN appointment_table a ON b.clientID = a.clientID AND b.join_to_billing = a.join_to_billing 
    WHERE
      CAST(b.date_of_service AS DATE) BETWEEN '2022-11-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
      AND (
        a.status_value IS NOT NULL OR b.date_of_service IS NOT NULL OR a.appointment_date IS NOT NULL
      )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      a.clientID AS ClientID,
      a.staff_name AS Staff,
      a.status_value AS AppointmentStatus,
      NULL AS DateOfService,
      FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d", a.appointment_date) AS ApptDate
    FROM
      appointment_table a
    WHERE
      CAST(a.appointment_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2022-11-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
      AND (
        a.status_value IS NOT NULL OR a.appointment_date IS NOT NULL
      )
  ) 
  ORDER BY ClientID
) b
WHERE
  b.ClientID IS NOT NULL &&
  b.Staff IS NOT NULL &&
  b.AppointmentStatus IS NOT NULL &&
  b.dos IS NOT NULL &&
  b.ApptDate IS NOT NULL
```